Why doesn't seem to be able to send an audio file with FRONT_COVER on the Pytelegrambotapi
In general the problem is that the audio file is sent to a file without a picture. I first thought that the problem is that the picture is installed on the wrong version of id3, and tried four methods of installation

via the ffmpeg command = [ “ffmpeg”, “-i”, file_path, “-i”, cover_path, “-map”, “0”, “-map”, “1”, “-c:a”, “copy”, “-c:v”, “mjpeg”, “-id3v2_version”, “3“,”-y”, output_file, ]subprocess.run(command, check=True)

via eyed3, audiofile.tag.images.set(
eyed3.id3.frames.ImageFrame.FRONT_COVER,
cover_data,
“` image/jpeg,
)

through the mutagen library, tried setting audio.add(
APIC(
encoding=3,
mime=“image/jpeg”,
type=3,
desc=“Cover”,
data=open(saved_photo, “rb”).read(),
)
)
At this stage I realized that the problem is not in the correct id3 tag setting, but in the method through which the audio file is sent. because if I opened it manually and sent it, the cover was there.
But I also tried installing the tag. second version. through the eyed3 library, but that also didn't result in the audio file with the cover art being sent to telegram.


audiofile w/ out cover
and the exact same audio file, only with the cover art. (it hasn't been altered in any way)



user_states = {}




def save_audio(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.audio.file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    user_dir = os.path.join("TEMP", str(message.chat.id), "albums")
    os.makedirs(user_dir, exist_ok=True)

    original_file_name = (
        message.audio.file_name
        if message.audio.file_name
        else f"{message.audio.file_id}.mp3"
    )

    file_path = os.path.join(user_dir, original_file_name)

    if message.chat.id not in user_states:
        user_states[message.chat.id] = {"files": [], "stage": None}

    with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(downloaded_file)

    user_states[message.chat.id]["files"].append(file_path)

    return file_path


def clear_metadata_for_file(file_path, user_id):
    clear_metadata = settings.get(str(user_id), {}).get("clear", True)

    if clear_metadata:
        temp_file_path = f"{file_path}.temp.mp3"
        command = [
            "ffmpeg",
            "-i",
            file_path,
            "-map_metadata",
            "-1",
            "-c:a",
            "copy",
            "-y",
            temp_file_path,
        ]
        subprocess.run(command, check=True)
        os.replace(temp_file_path, file_path)

        audio_file = eyed3.load(file_path)
        if audio_file.tag is not None:
            audio_file.tag.clear()
        audio_file.tag.save()

    else:
        return file_path


def send_files(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    if chat_id not in user_states or "files" not in user_states[chat_id]:
        return "No files found"

    for file_path in user_states[chat_id]["files"]:
        try:
            with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
                bot.send_audio(chat_id, f)
        except Exception as e:
            return e



@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def handle_cover(message):

    if message.content_type == "photo":
        try:

            saved_photo = save_photo(message)


            for file_path in user_states[message.chat.id]["files"]:

                audio = ID3(file_path)
                audio.add(
                    APIC(
                        encoding=3,
                        mime="image/jpeg",
                        type=3,
                        desc="Cover",
                        data=open(saved_photo, "rb").read(),
                    )
                )
                audio.save(file_path)
                with open(saved_photo, "rb") as image_file:
                    image_data = image_file.read()

                audiofile = eyed3.load(file_path)

                if audiofile.tag is None:
                    audiofile.initTag(version=(2, 3, 0))

                audiofile.tag.images.set(
                    3, image_data, "image/jpeg", description="Cover"
                )
                audiofile.tag.save(version=(2, 3, 0))

            send_files(message)

        except Exception as e:
            return

bot.infinity_polling()


I was hoping to get some audio files with cover art, and I'm sure there's no problem with that. But for some reason, the file itself is sent visually without the cover art. I'd really appreciate it if you could help me out with this.
